# How to remove anything in a string after "-"?

Tags: php, regex

This is the example of my string.

```
$x = "John Chio - Guy";
$y = "Kelly Chua - Woman";
```

I need the pattern for the reg replace.

```
$pattern = ??
$x = preg_replace($pattern, '', $x);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No need for regex. You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$str = array_shift(explode('-', $str));
```

or [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
```

Maybe in combination with [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

**Update:** As @Mark points out this will fail if the part you want to get contains a `-`. It all depends on your possible input.

So assuming you want to remove everything after the **last** dash, you can use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), which finds the last occurrence of a substring:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '-'));
```

So you see, there is no regular expression needed ;)

Comment: @Mark Byers: Depends, it still removes everything after the `-` as the question demands ;) But considering the structure in the question, this could solved by exploding on ` - ` (space minus space).

Comment: Personally I prefer the second option using `substr` as the `array_shift` option gives you the `only variables should be passed by reference` warning with PHP 5.3.

Comment: If the string does not have any - it will return null instead of the string using second option

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok):

```
$x = strtok($x, '-');
```

Answer (score 9):

To remove everything after the **first** hyphen you can use this regular expression in your code:

```
"/-.*$/"
```

To remove everything after the **last** hyphen you can use this regular expression:

```
"/-[^-]*$/"
```

http://ideone.com/gbLA9

You can also combine this with trimming whitespace from the end of the result:

```
"/\s*-[^-]*$/"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use.

```
strstr( "John Chio - Guy", "-", true ) . '-';
```

The third parameter `true` tells the function to return everything before first occurrence of the second parameter.

[Source on strstr() from php.net](http://php.net/strstr)

Comment: Would your solution be more efficient than using '$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str,'-'));' as given in a couple of answers above? Based on the fact that it's not using nested functions, I'd assume it is more efficient but that's not necessarily the case. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I hope these patterns will help you =]

```
$pattern1='/.+(?=\s-)/'       //This will match the string before the " -";
$pattern2='/(?<=\s-\s).+/'    //This will match the string after the "- ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode or regexp are an overkill, try this:

`$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str,'-'));`

or the strtok version in one of the answers here.

Comment: Fails for double-barrelled names: http://ideone.com/Ufu3h See here for a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705167/how-to-remove-anything-in-a-string-after/4705179#4705179

Answer (score -1):

Use the `strstr` function.

**Example:**

```
$my_string = "This is my best string - You like it?";
$my_new_string = strstr($my_string, '-', true);

echo($my_new_string);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answer given by user2453885, about 8months earlier.